# formatting numbers in text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the "Letters" smaller than the numbers.  Also, numbers should be bold.

for example in ABC123DDD8877 I want to display 123 and then 8877 two times bigger than characters.

how it possible in html, css or javascript?

Comment: Some context is required. Where is that string?

Comment: in a table. not static string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript:

```
$('#output').html(($('#output').html()).replace(/[0-9]/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>'))
```

Check Output: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wLd5E/2/

Comment: Good, can I give some css to this. so the numbers 2 times biger than characters.

Comment: yes, you can apply css on <strong> tags 

$('#output').html(($('#output').html()).replace(/[0-9]/gi, '<strong style="font-size:20pt">$&</strong>'))

Comment: very good done. thanks

Comment: hi Qambar Raza, your example is correct, but how can I implement it? is there any need to attach jQuery file?

Comment: yes just add this <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> - if you use pure javascript without any framework the line of code and complexity will increase.

Comment: hi Qambar, I used it with the following:                            <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
jQ('#multi-record-table td:nth-child(8)').html(($('#multi-record-table td:nth-child(8)').
html()).replace(/[0-9]/gi, '<big><big>$&</big></big>'));
}); I am facing a problem, it don't pick the column values of the table. repeat the first value in the column.

Answer (score 1):

```
ABC<span class="num">123</span>DDD<span class="num">8877</span>
```

And then add some CSS for `.num`...

```
body {  /* Assuming "default" font-size of 10pt for your page */
    font-size:10pt;
}
.num {
    font-size:20pt; /* 2 x 10pt = 20pt */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hubeJ/1/

Comment: thanks robiii, not static string.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not static string"??

Comment: for example my table have such data: ABC222DD33, 12GGFF322LLKD, DDFD23121ERER, 1212KDKD322HJH